# ActiveAdmin Gem: Redirect user to login page if not logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am working with active admin gem and it is working great.
But a minor that I'm facing is whenever I manually enter a url such as:

```
https://www.example.com/admin/users/5
```

and if the admin is not logged in then the above url page shows:

```
{"errors":["You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."]}
```

which is fine, but I want a redirection to the login page and if admin log in from the page, it should show up the desired page pointing to `https://www.example.com/admin/users/5`

I'm not able to figure out the redirection procedure for ActiveAdmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In config/initializers/active_admin.rb you have such config

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
```

then create a method named authenticate_admin_user! in the ApplicationController

```
def authenticate_admin_user!
  #check for current_user if not then redirect to login
end
```